# android-not getting firebase cloud functions database user id

Tags: android

Can someone help me with this code? I'm trying to get the user id but it shows something like

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
>       at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:9:30)
>       at Object. (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27)
>       at next (native)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
>       at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
>       at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
>       at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:710:26
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

here is my code (index.js):

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{uid}/{notification_id}').onWrite(event => {

    const user_id = event.params.uid;
    const notification = event.params.notification;

    console.log('We have notification to sent to : ', user_id);

    if(!event.data.val()){
        return console.log("A notification has been deleted from the database : ", notification_id);
    }

    const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${uid}/device_token`).once('value');

    return deviceToken.then(result => {

        const token_id = result.val();

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Friend Request",
                body: "You have received a new friend request",
                icon: "default"
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response => {

            return console.log("This was the notification feature");

        });



    });



});
```

Comment: Replace `uid` with `user_id` during retrieval so its `Users/${user_id}/device_token`